# Is there a way to perform certain action by only first user at the end of test?

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I have just started using locust with one custom client. At the end of the test (on_stop) I am fetching some results from APM and logging them.

**Issue** : when I use below command, all 1000 users are fetching those details and logging the data from APM. But I want only the 1st user to do this job and let other users to ignore this call.

`$ locust -f --headless -u 1000 -r 100 --run-time 1h30m`

Please let me know if someone has done something similar earlier. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you probably want is `test_stop` EventHook. It runs once when the test is stopped. If you run in distributed mode, it runs once only on the master.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.test_stop

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are not running in distributed mode and you are using User class' on_stop method. I would try handling it with some global variable, it is quick and might need some work, like this:

```
apm_logging_user_assigned = False
class MyUser(User):
    test stuff here ...

    def on_start(self):
        if apm_logging_user_assigned is False:
            self.apm_log = True
            apm_logging_user_assigned = True
        super().on_start()

    def on_stop(self):
        if self.apm_log:
            do your apm stuff here...
        super().on_stop()
```

Comment: you are correct, I am not running in distributed mode. If I am running with `-u 15` wouldn't `on_stop(self)` would be called 15 times? causing 15 entries..


causing 15 entries?

Comment: on_stop would be called 15 times but we are checking if the user eligible for logging with `self.apm_log` and only 1 user will be assigned to it because when we assign it we change the global variable apm_logging_user_assigned thus only one user will be eligible for logging, so you log only once. If you can access the stats you want to log with some other method you can use @Solowalker s answer too it would be more  elegant I think